# Military Time Form Validation msAccess Form View

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having a difficult time doing military time or short time in the form view. I caught an error where the user put in 15:83 which shouldn't be allowed because the minutes are over 59, as well hours being over 23. However, I'm not sure how to create a form validation for something like that and I can't seem to find any documentation for it online surrounding this type of formatting.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Access?

Comment: Explain what military time or short is.

Comment: I'm using access, essentially creating form validation on the front end for it however, if it's in HH:MM then not isNULL([table]) and HH <=23 and MM <=59

Comment: @jarlh: "Military time" is a common term in English-speaking 12-hour (1-12 AM/PM) countries to refer to the 24-hour (0-23) time format.

Comment: If you are wanting only numeric values and those values need to fall within a specific range you should probably use a spinedit control and set the min and max values allowed. Seems to me that if you use a better choice for the user input you can control this easily.

Comment: So the form control is bound to a text field in the form's data source?  If you change the datatype of that field from text to Date/Time, Access won't accept an invalid time (such as "15:83") in that control.

Comment: If the field must remain as text type, see whether using `IsDate()` in the control's Validation Rule is satisfactory: `IsDate([YourControlName])=True`

Comment: @hansup I have tried it as Short Time which is the more defined version of Date/Time seen within design view yet it's still letting me put in 99:99 and doesn't restrict it to specifically HH <= 23 and MM <=59 which I find a little bit weird. It's a text field in the form view so I tried doing the operation you shared earlier but that didn't work either where it's IsDate([Time]) =True.

Comment: Apply a date or time format, that's enough to have a native validity control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the validation rule property of the text box control on the form enter this expression

=Right([Text6],2)<60 Or Left([Text6],2)<24

i have assumed name of control is Text6

Comment: This worked perfectly I used the and operator instead of OR and that made it work. Thank you so much Sola Oshinowo! If I was high enough reputation I would upvote!

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to find any documentation for it online surrounding this
> type of formatting.

That's because it is difficult and requires quite a lot of code, too much to post here. But, for example, to correct invalid input:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
  
    Const TimeHourMaximum   As Integer = 24
    Const TimeHourDefault   As Integer = 20
    Const TimeMinuteTenMax  As Integer = 5
    
    Dim ctl                 As Control
    
    Dim Text                As String
    Dim SelStart            As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set ctl = Screen.ActiveControl
    
    Select Case ctl.Name
        Case "Logon"
            Text = ctl.Text
            SelStart = ctl.SelStart
            If Not IsDate(Text) Then
                DoCmd.Beep
                If Val(Left(Text, 2)) > TimeHourMaximum Then
                    Mid(Text, 1) = CStr(TimeHourDefault)
                ElseIf Len(Text) > 3 Then
                    ' Length of Text is larger than two hour digits and the kolon.
                    Mid(Text, 1 + 3) = CStr(TimeMinuteTenMax)
                End If
            End If
            ctl.Text = Text
            ctl.SelStart = SelStart
            ctl.SelLength = 1
            Response = acDataErrContinue
    End Select

    Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Full code, documentation, and a demo application is posted with my project `VBA.TimeEntry` at GitHub:

[Entering 24-hour time with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.TimeEntry)

[image]